# React bootstrap typeahead clearButton icon (X) does not appear for a single selection

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I have tried selecting clearButton prop for a single selection input. However it does not work as expected. The clear (x) icon does not appear with a default selected input. It appears only once there is an event change, that is if I select some other input. My problem is that removing the input manually does not trigger a change in the selected value. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
<Typeahead
  clearButton
  defaultInputValue={props.city}
  options={props.cityOptions}
  onChange={(selected) => handleCityFieldChange(selected[0], props)}
  placeholder="Choose a city"
/>
```

Here's the handleCityFieldChange function:

```
handleCityFieldChange = (selected, props) => {
    const newFieldValues = Object.assign({}, props.fieldValues, {"city": selected});
    props.onChange(newFieldValues);
};
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: ` <Typeahead
                    clearButton
                    options={props.cityOptions}
                    placeholder="Choose a city"
                    defaultInputValue={props.city}
                    onChange={(selected) => handleCityFieldChange(selected[0], props)}/> `

Comment: Say if the city field shows an already persisted city from the database, there is no X icon at the time of view. It is only if i select some other city, the X icon appears.

Answer (score 2):

Use `defaultSelected`, not `defaultInputValue`:

```
<Typeahead
  clearButton
  defaultSelected={props.city}
  options={props.cityOptions}
  onChange={(selected) => handleCityFieldChange(selected[0], props)}
  placeholder="Choose a city"
/>
```

The clear button only appears when there is a *selection*. `defaultInputValue` sets the `value` of the input, without actually selecting an option, which is why you weren't seeing the button.

Note: `defaultSelected` expects an array, so if `props.city` is an object, you'll need to pass `[props.city]`.

Comment: so using defaultSelected for my use case worked the way i expected. not sure if i messed something else, but if pass [props.city], i get the error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'paginationOption' of undefined

Comment: I'm not clear from your comment whether you go this working or not. What does `props.city` look like? This kind of info should be posted in your question. Help me help you :)

Comment: sorry if that wasn't clear in my last comment. Using defaultSelected={[props.city]} worked in getting the clear icon getting displayed. props.city is a String here. But now if i clear the selected option, i am not able to re-select any city. And i see the "Uncaught TypeError" i referred in the last comment in my console.

Comment: So i was able to work around the Uncaught TypeError after checking for undefined in the the handleCityFieldChange function. Added this line: `if (!selected) {selected=""};`